# Matplotlib subplot - chart is overwritten

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I want to create two pie charts based on the following data:

```
post_type   owner_user_id   year_posted score   count
A           150165022       332372      2567380 35846
Q           112349610       283997       180680 2111
```

one by `score` and one by `count` grouped by `post_type`. So, I am using the following code:

```
axes[0].labels = ['answers', 'questions']
axes[0].sizes = buffer_df['score']
axes[0].explode = (0, 0.3)
axes[0].pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True, startangle=90)
axes[0].axis('equal')

axes[1].labels = ['answers a', 'questions a']
axes[1].sizes = buffer_df['count']
axes[1].explode = (0, 0.3)
axes[1].pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True, startangle=90)
axes[1].axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

but I am getting only the first chart drawn two times:

[image]

I know it's the first chart, as I change the labels of the second one.

Could anyone tell, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this is so, but if you describe it directly, you can draw what you intend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes= plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(12,9))

axes[0].pie(buffer_df['score'], explode=(0, 0.3), labels=['answers', 'questions'], autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True, startangle=90)
axes[0].axis('equal')
axes[1].pie(buffer_df['count'], explode=(0, 0.3), labels=['answers a', 'questions a'], autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True, startangle=90)
axes[1].axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

[image]